# Weird behaviour of Fisheye Distortion plugin

Tags: javascript, graphics, d3.js, fisheye

Hi I would like to use [Fisheye Distortion plugin](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/) for my force-directed graph in *d3.js*, but when I want to apply this plugin, behaviour of graph is weird. I am new in *d3.js* and not good at computer graphics.

[complete sample in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/90u4sjzm/21/)

```
var fisheye = d3.fisheye.circular()
                        .radius(200)
                        .distortion(2);

    // graph - variable which represents whole graph                    
    graph.svg.on("mousemove", function() {
    fisheye.focus(d3.mouse(this));

    d3.select("svg").selectAll("circle").each(function(d) { d.fisheye = fisheye(d); })
                                .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.fisheye.x; })
                                .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.fisheye.y; })
                                .attr("r", function(d) { return d.fisheye.z * 4.5; });


    d3.select("svg").selectAll("line").attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.fisheye.x; })
                                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.fisheye.y; })
                                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.fisheye.x; })
                                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.fisheye.y; });   
                    });
```

Weird behaviour I mean the nodes of graph disappear (are hidden) after mouseover action.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this working example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/)?

Comment: Yes i saw that example

Comment: It looks like it is working fine on your graph. How's it different from what you expected.

Comment: @ArunR I don't understand what do you mean working fine. In my case nodes of graph disappear after mouseover action. Please see my edited question.

Comment: @Matt Ok I see it now. I feel like it might be related to the nodes' scaling factor. After the plugin they seem to be offset, but at a smaller size. Can you reduce their scaling factor (maybe use the default value) and see if it fixes it?

Comment: @ArunR thanks for response. if i have more time i will try it.

Comment: @ArunR i tried to change(reduce) node scaling factor, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you were using the code to add `cx` and `cy` to circles, but your circles were actually enclosed inside `nodeElements` which were `transform`ed into place.

Hence, changing the fisheye code to the following solves the problem:

```
graph.svg.on("mousemove", function() {
    fisheye.focus(d3.mouse(this));

    // Change transform on the .node
    d3.select("svg").selectAll(".node")
    .each(function(d) { d.fisheye = fisheye({ x: graph.x(d.x), y: graph.y(d.y) }); console.log(d.fisheye, d); })
    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.fisheye.x + "," + d.fisheye.y + ")"; })
    // Now change the 'r'adius on the circles within
    // One can also scale the font of the text inside nodeElements here
    .select("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return 15 * graph.nodeSizeFactor * d.fisheye.z; });


    d3.select("svg").selectAll("line")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.fisheye.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.fisheye.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.fisheye.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.fisheye.y; });   
});
```

Note that I have also applied the proper scales `graph.x` and `graph.y` for the `transform` attribute and `15 * graph.nodeSizeFactor` for the radius of the circles (instead of `4.5`).

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/90u4sjzm/23/